# WHMCS changing database

Tags: php, whmcs

I'm still trying to understand why in WHMCS on the same MySQL database if I try to connect to a different db, he still tries to search a table in his default database.
Example: I'm trying to connect to the table "test" in "admin_test" so he needs to search for "admin_test.test", but instead he gives me the error:
VPN Database Query Error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'admin_billing.test' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `test` (`user_id`) values (fdffddfg))

So I think he doesn't want to change db, I tried to write this module based on the freeradius module, as it works fine and has his own db on the same localhost mysql.. I don't know how to fix this as of now.

```
function rscmodule_DatabaseInsert()
{
        
    try {

    $vpnsql = rscmodule_DatabaseConnect();
    if (is_string($vpnsql)) {
        return $vpnsql; // Error condition
    }
    

        
        Capsule::connection()->transaction(
        function ($vpnsql)
        {
            /** @var \Illuminate\Database\Connection $connectionManager */
            $vpnsql->table('test')->insert(
                [
                    'user_id' => 'fdffddfg',
                ]
            );
        }
    );
        
        

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return "VPN Database Query Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    return "success";
                
    
}



function rscmodule_DatabaseConnect()
{   
        $pdo = null;
    try {
        $pdo = Capsule::getInstance()->getConnection('rscmodule');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {

        $config = array(
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'database' => 'admin_test',
            'username' => 'admin_test',
            'password' => '*****',
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
        );

        try {
            Capsule::getInstance()->addConnection(
                $config,
                'rscmodule'
            );

            $pdo = Capsule::getInstance()->getConnection('rscmodule');

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return "Unable to connect to rscmodule Database.  "
            . "Please check rscmodule server configuration.  "
            . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    if (is_object($pdo)) {
        if (method_exists($pdo, 'query')) {
            $ret = $pdo->query();
        } else {
            $processor = $pdo->getPostProcessor();
            $ret = new \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder($pdo, $pdo->getQueryGrammar(), $processor);
        }
    } else {
        $ret = $pdo;
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well turns out WHMCS doesn't want other DBs inside the same connection IP, so we created a VM on a new IP and on that the connection works properly.